# Trying to reformat timestamp in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't seem to find a question/answer that works for what I'm trying to achieve. Currently, this is how my DB outputs a timestamp:

```
2015-08-18T19:43:04.738-06:00
```

However, I would like it to appear as such in the column:

```
2015-08-18T19:43:04.738 America/Denver
```

Google has recently changed their formatting options and instead of downloading the output and performing a find/replace, I want an output that doesn't require additional work. I looked on SO and have tried using trim and replace but having no luck.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: -06:00 includes a number of locations. Is there any other info in the table pointing to  America/Denver ?

Comment: What type are you storing timestamps as? `timestamp with time zone`?

Comment: Do you need the full timezone name, or you can use abbreviation such as `MDT` ?

Comment: @Serg No, I'm afraid not.

Comment: @Schwern Yes, I believe so. I haven't been able to confirm with my engineer but I believe that's true.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I'm afraid the abbreviation doesn't work. Here are the approved timestamp formats for Google Ads: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7014069. For whatever reason, the one we've used since February (third from the bottom) no longer works. When I've manually reformatted in my upload doc, only the last two seem to work.

Comment: @JoshuaFortunatus That's just the first two characters, `20`.

Answer (score 0):

> *For whatever reason, the one we've used since February (third from the bottom) no longer works.*

`2015-08-18T19:43:04.738-06:00` is not quite the right format. Google does not accept milliseconds (which is annoying if they don't just ignore it). You need to send `2015-08-18T19:43:04-06:00`. They may have become more strict in what they accept.

Try `date_trunc('second', yourtime)`.

---

It's not possible to *accurately* translate an offset like `-0600` to a time zone like `America/Denver`. They say two different things.

`-0600` says, with absolute certainty, that this time is 6 hours behind [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC). 12:00:00-06:00 and 18:00:00Z (Z represents UTC) are the same time.

`America/Denver` means to interpret this timestamp under the rules applicable to the city of Denver, Colorado, USA at that time. To figure out what time it is in UTC you need to look up the offset rules for Denver, Colorado, USA. The offset will change depending on the time of year, usually because of daylight savings time. Because the rules change, it's important to apply the rules ***as they were at that time***.

For example, [`2006-03-15 12:00 America/Denver` is -0700](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20060315T190000&p1=75&p2=tz_gmt). But the next year on [`2007-03-15 12:00 America/Denver` is -0600](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20070315T180000&p1=75&p2=tz_gmt). Between 2006 and 2007 [the daylight savings time rules in the US changed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States#2005%E2%80%932009:_Second_extension).

Whereas `-06:00` avoids all that and simply says the time is offset from UTC by six hours.

You could fake it by simply replacing the offset with `America/Denver`. So long as you're only sending recent times that should work. You'll be off by at most an hour. But don't do that.

Unless Google Ads specifically needs a time zone there's no point in sending them one. Internally, Postgres is storing your times in UTC anyway and translating them to your server's time zone, `America/Denver`. Send Google UTC. And, as noted above, chop off the milliseconds.

```
select date_trunc('second', '2015-08-18T19:43:04.738-06:00'::timestamp with time zone at time zone 'UTC') as datetime;
      datetime       
---------------------
 2015-08-19 01:43:04
```